# Bicep -Can not perform requested operation on nested resource

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-bicep

I encountered this error in the bicep file while creating function app with VNET integration. My Vnet is in another resource group named 'tst-vnet' separate from my function app. Is there a way to resolve this? Here is the code snippet:

```
   resource functionApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2022-03-01' = {
       name: functionAppName
       location: location
       tags: tags
       kind: 'functionapp'
       identity: {
         type: 'SystemAssigned'
       }
       properties: {
         httpsOnly: true
         serverFarmId: functionAppHostingPlan.id
         clientAffinityEnabled: true
         publicNetworkAccess: 'Disabled'
         siteConfig: {
           appSettings: [
             {
               name: 'AzureWebJobsStorage'
               value: 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=${functionAppStorageAccount.name};EndpointSuffix=${environment().suffixes.storage};AccountKey=${listKeys(functionAppStorageAccount.id, functionAppStorageAccount.apiVersion).keys[0].value}'
             }
             {
               name: 'FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION'
               value: runtimeStackVersion
             }
             {
               name: 'FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME'
               value: runtimeStack
             }
             {
               name: 'WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING'
               value: 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=${functionAppStorageAccount.name};EndpointSuffix=${environment().suffixes.storage};AccountKey=${listKeys(functionAppStorageAccount.id, functionAppStorageAccount.apiVersion).keys[0].value}'
             }
             {
               name: 'WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE'
               value: 'functionapp'
             }
             {
               name: 'WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL'
               value: '1'
             }
             {
               name: 'WEBSITE_DNS_SERVER'
               value: '168.63.129.16'
             }
             {
               name: 'WEBSITE_CONTENTOVERVNET'
               value: '1'
             }
           ]
           minTlsVersion: '1.2'
           linuxFxVersion: linuxFxVersion
           ftpsState: 'FtpsOnly'
         }
       }
     }
```

I created a module to in order to use a resource group scope in order to reference the 'tst-vnet'

```
module networkConfig 'modules/network-config.bicep' = {
   name: '${deploymentPrefix}-fn-networkcfg' 
   dependsOn: [
     functionApp
   ]
   scope: resourceGroup(pvtResourceGroupName)
   params: {
     functionAppName: functionAppName
     privateBackendSubnet: privateBackendSubnet
     privateEndpointVNet: privateEndpointVNet
     privateBackendSubnetCIDR: privateBackendSubnetCIDR
   }
 }
```

This is the content of network-config.bicep

```
 resource networkConfig 'Microsoft.Web/sites/networkConfig@2022-03-01' = {
   name: '${functionAppName}/virtualNetwork'
   properties: {
     subnetResourceId: resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', privateEndpointVNet, privateBackendSubnet)
     swiftSupported: true
   }
 }
```

Full error from resource group deployment

{
"status": "Failed",
"error": {
"code": "DeploymentFailed",
"message": "At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.",
"details": [
{
"code": "NotFound",
"message": "{\r\n  "error": {\r\n    "code": "ParentResourceNotFound",\r\n    "message": "**Can not perform requested operation on nested resource. Parent resource 'ase-data-tst-edp-fn-001' not found**."\r\n  }\r\n}"
}
]

Comment: Culd you please share the full error message ? also you could always reference the subnet resource id like that: `resourceId('<vnet resource group name>','Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', privateEndpointVNet, privateBackendSubnet)`

Comment: Could you please try to deploy azure function with v-net integration in a same resource group. Reference:- [*GitHub*](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/quickstarts/microsoft.web/function-premium-vnet-integration/main.bicep)

Comment: @AjayKumarGhose that will work but that's not my use case here

Comment: @Thomas I'll update the question to include the full error of the deployment

Answer (score 0):

When declaring a module, you can set a scope for the module that is different than the scope for the containing Bicep file. In your scenario, as you have existing virtual network, which is different scope, the virtual network should be declared in separate module. For your reference, you can use below template to deploy the function app integrating with virtual network which is in another resource group.

main.bicep file

```
@description('Location for all resources except Application Insights.')
param location string = resourceGroup().location

@description('Location for Application Insights.')
param appInsightsLocation string

@description('The language worker runtime to load in the function app.')
@allowed([
  'node'
  'dotnet'
  'java'
])
param runtime string = 'node'

@description('The name of the function app that you wish to create.')
param appName string = 'fnapp${uniqueString(resourceGroup().id)}'

@description('Storage Account type')
@allowed([
  'Standard_LRS'
  'Standard_GRS'
  'Standard_RAGRS'
])
param storageAccountType string = 'Standard_LRS'

@description('The name of the virtual network to be linked.')
param vnetName string

@description('The name of the subnet to be created within the virtual network.')
param subnetName string

@description('The name of the resource group where existing virtual network exists.')
param vnresourceGroup string

var functionAppName = appName
var hostingPlanName = appName
var storageAccountName = '${uniqueString(resourceGroup().id)}azfunctions'
var functionWorkerRuntime = runtime

resource virtualNetwork 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks@2020-06-01' existing = {
  name: vnetName
  scope: resourceGroup(vnresourceGroup)
}

resource storageAccount 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2021-04-01' = {
  name: storageAccountName
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: storageAccountType
  }
  kind: 'StorageV2'
}

resource appInsights 'Microsoft.Insights/components@2020-02-02' = {
  name: functionAppName
  location: appInsightsLocation
  kind: 'web'
  properties: {
    Application_Type: 'web'
  }
}

resource serverFarm 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2020-06-01' = {
  name: hostingPlanName
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: 'EP1'
    tier: 'ElasticPremium'
  }
  kind: 'elastic'
  properties: {
    maximumElasticWorkerCount: 20
  }
}

resource function 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2020-06-01' = {
  name: functionAppName
  location: location
  kind: 'functionapp'
  properties: {
    serverFarmId: serverFarm.id
    siteConfig: {
      appSettings: [
        {
          name: 'APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY'
          value: appInsights.properties.InstrumentationKey
        }
        {
          name: 'APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING'
          value: 'InstrumentationKey=${appInsights.properties.InstrumentationKey}'
        }
        {
          name: 'AzureWebJobsStorage'
          value: 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=${storageAccount.name};EndpointSuffix= ${environment().suffixes.storage};AccountKey=${storageAccount.listKeys().keys[0].value}'
        }
        {
          name: 'WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING'
          value: 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=${storageAccountName};EndpointSuffix=${environment().suffixes.storage};AccountKey=${storageAccount.listKeys().keys[0].value};'
        }
        {
          name: 'FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION'
          value: '~3'
        }
        {
          name: 'FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME'
          value: functionWorkerRuntime
        }
        {
          name: 'WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION'
          value: '~12'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
  dependsOn: [
    virtualNetwork
  ]
}

resource networkConfig 'Microsoft.Web/sites/networkConfig@2020-06-01' = {
  parent: function
  name: 'virtualNetwork'
  properties: {
    subnetResourceId: subnet.outputs.subnetId
    swiftSupported: true
  }
  dependsOn: [
    subnet
  ]
}

module subnet 'modules/subnet.bicep' = {
  name: subnetName
  scope: resourceGroup(vnresourceGroup)
  params: {
    subnetName: subnetName
    subnetPrefix: '10.2.1.0/24'
    vnetName: vnetName
  }
}
```

subnet.bicep

```
@description('The name of the virtual network to be linked.')
param vnetName string

@description('The name of the subnet to be created within the virtual network.')
param subnetName string

@description('The address Prefix of subnet to be created within the virtual network.')
param subnetPrefix string 

param deploySubnet bool = true

resource VNET 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks@2021-02-01' existing  = {
  name: vnetName
  
}

resource Subnets 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets@2020-11-01'= if (deploySubnet)   {
  name: subnetName
  parent: VNET
  properties: {
    addressPrefix: subnetPrefix
    privateEndpointNetworkPolicies: 'Disabled'
    privateLinkServiceNetworkPolicies: 'Enabled'
    delegations: [
      {
          name: 'Microsoft.Web.serverFarms'
          properties: {
              serviceName: 'Microsoft.Web/serverFarms'
          }
      }
  ]
  }
}

output subnetId string = deploySubnet ? Subnets.id:''
```